# Store content of jquery load() function into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I want the content of my `load()` function to be stored into a variable so to pass it into another function. The project is to pass it as a sting to a function that creates a toast message in a `webview` for android phones! 
My code is :

```
$( '#lightson' ).click( function () {
            $.get( 'http://<?php echo $_SESSION['ip']?>/?2', {}, callbacka() );
            function callbacka() {

                var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
                var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;

                if(isAndroid) {

                Android.showToast("**Here I want to put my content**");

                }
                    else {

                        $('.status2').load('status2.php').delay(3000).queue(function() {
                        $('.status2').empty().dequeue();
                        });

                    }
            }
    } );
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

### AHHHH!

You are running your callback immediately! Remove the `()`:

```
$.get( 'http://<?php echo $_SESSION['ip']?>/?2', {}, callbacka );
```

Comment: OK for that, but what about my question? I want where the **Here I want to put my content** is to dynamicly put my `load()` content

Comment: also for the `()` I have a problem that I describe here:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627985/my-jquery-queued-functions-fail-to-run-after-the-first-time)

Comment: No one can help me with this problem? I want to store the result of load() into a variable...